# How to use latest gradle-ospackage-plugin from GitHub

Tags: java, rpm, gradle-plugin, netflix-nebula-plugins

I have recently upgraded to Gradle 8 finding out that the `nebula.ospackage` plugin distributed in [Gradle plugin Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/) is not compatible.

In [gradle-ospackage-plugin GitHub](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin) repo, there's the 11 version which claim to resolve the incompatibility with Gradle 8.

This code doesn't work:

```
plugins {
    id "nebula.ospackage" version "11.0.0"
}
```

with:

```
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'nebula.ospackage:nebula.ospackage.gradle.plugin:11.0.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

How to use in Gradle a plugin from GitHub and not from the official Gradle Plugin site?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the way to use the latest gradle ospackage plugin, it has just changed name from `nebula.ospackage` to `com.netflix.nebula.ospackage` so:

```
plugins {
    id "com.netflix.nebula.ospackage" version "11.0.0"
}
```

works perfectly !